# Сохранение и загрузка определённой Activity в Android приложении

Tags: java, android

Разрабатываю приложение адаптацию для определённого алгоритма. В нём будет 6 основных категорий, в которых будут подэтапы. Некоторые ведут на другие категории. Застрял на этапе создания функции сохранения. Оно должно работать даже после закрытия приложения. По сути у меня есть 2 основных вопроса:

1. Как лучше организовать мелкие вопросы: как отдельные активити, на которые будет переход по кнопкам, или просто создать для них фрагменты?
2. Для переходов между этапами я использую Intent, в котором нужно указывать название класса, на который осуществляется переход. Можно ли как-либо сохранить имя класса для дальнейшего передачи в основную активность (с неё будет идти загрузка) или можно создать отдельную переменную метку, на которую будет ссылаться intent? Если лучше этапы в категории как фрагменты, то какую метку использовать в них?

Comment: Избегайте задавать несколько вопросов в одном.

Comment: если у вас несколько проблем, создайте несколько вопросов - в одном вопросе должна быть только одна проблема